# Providing a correct std::copy_if predicate

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, copy, predicate

The aim of the example program is to copy every third item from `source` to target with `std::copy_if`.
Based in the [reference](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_if/), the copy should happen whenever the predicate returns with true, but this is not the case with the below code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using std::vector;

int main(int argc, char** agrs){
    vector<double> source(15, 0.5);
    vector<double> target(15, 1.1);
    int index = 0;
    std::copy_if(
        source.begin(),source.end(),target.begin(),
        [&](double number){
            index = ((index + 1) % 3);
            std::cout << "["<< index << "]->" << (0 == index) << "\t";
            return (0 == index);
        }
    );
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::for_each(source.begin(),source.end(),[](double value){
            std::cout << "["<< value << "]\t";
    });
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::for_each(target.begin(),target.end(),[](double value){
            std::cout << "["<< value << "]\t";
    });
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is the following:

```
[1]->0  [2]->0  [0]->1  [1]->0  [2]->0  [0]->1  [1]->0  [2]->0  [0]->1  [1]->0  [2]->0  [0]->1  [1]->0  [2]->0  [0]->1
[0.5]   [0.5]   [0.5]   [0.5]   [0.5]   [0.5]   [0.5]   [0.5]   [0.5]   [0.5]   [0.5]   [0.5]   [0.5]   [0.5]   [0.5]
[0.5]   [0.5]   [0.5]   [0.5]   [0.5]   [1.1]   [1.1]   [1.1]   [1.1]   [1.1]   [1.1]   [1.1]   [1.1]   [1.1]   [1.1]
```

The first row is showing the actual copying as well as the return value of the output predicate.
The second row is the source vector, and the third is the target vector.

It would be fair to expect every 3rd element to be copied, based on the predicate, however that is not the case?

Why is that? How can the logic be fixed to fulfill its intended purpose?

Comment: copy_if doesn't advance the target iterator when a copy doesn't happen. you seem to expect it to march alongside the source iterator, retaining original content of every non-over-written slot. If you have 15 source slots and only copy 5 of them, the target iterator will only advance five times (one for each copied element). I suspect a better fit would be something like `std::transform` with a conditional case of whether to pull from the source or not.

Comment: `index = ((++index) % 3);` Are you sure this isn't undefined behavior? Cf. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: if that is the case, then definitely! Is this mentioned anywhere in the reference?

Comment: i am always a little confused by that obsession with post/preincrement, wouldnt it be much clearer to write `index = ((index +1) %3)` ?

Comment: I modified it, but it's the same behavior.

Comment: sometimes cplusplus has wrong/misleading information. They write "result [...] The range includes as many elements as [first,last)." which is wrong.

Comment: Not sure that stateful predicate is allowed BTW.

Comment: I adapted the code to use std::for_each, and it indeed works like that, but the question could be useful in the perspective of std::copy_if I think.

Comment: @Jarod42 no it isnt because algorithms are free to copy predicates

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: copy in that case is not a problem as state is "shared"(capture by reference).. but `pred(it) != pred(it)` can happen and not sure that order of predicate calls is guaranty.

Comment: @Jarod42 oh right. Not authorative, but cppref writes " starting from first and proceeding to last - 1" for `std::copy` and I assumed that same applies for `copy_if` (without an ExecutionPolicy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, sometimes cplusplus has wrong/misleading information. [They write:](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_if/)

> result
>
> Output iterator to the initial position of the range where the resulting sequence is stored. The range includes as many elements as [first,last).

And that is wrong. The output range has as many elements as the predicate returns `true`. Others are not copied and the target iterator is not incremented in that case. `copy_if` works just like expected in your example.

I suggest this reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy

It also does not mention explicitly that the output iterator is only advanced when actually an element was copied. But it also does not state otherwise. Looking at the possible implementation should make things more clear:

> ```
> template<class InputIt, class OutputIt, class UnaryPredicate>
> OutputIt copy_if(InputIt first, InputIt last, 
>                  OutputIt d_first, UnaryPredicate pred)
> {
>     while (first != last) {
>         if (pred(*first))
>             *d_first++ = *first;
>         first++;
>     }
>     return d_first;
> }
> ```

You can see that `d_first` is only incremented when `pred(*first)` returns `true`.

Comment: cplusplus.com has become for C++ what basically W3Schools was for web development in the '00s. It maddens me it's always the first result on Google, especially since it's often incorrect and it lacks almost all of C++17 and C++20.

Comment: @mcilloni I tripped over it two or three times. It caused really serious issues in my code. Since then I just pick the second google hit. I mean cppref isnt perfect either, but I know how to fix an error when I see one, and not pretending to be a tutorial is also worth a lot these days